# Problems with TTY and ALT+F4

Tags: shortcut-keys, tty

so I don't know why but when I type <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> Ubuntu firstly pass to `TTY4` and when I go back to `TTY7` to login in my previous screen, after entered, it'll close the window (that I was trying to close).

What I would to do is:

1. Don't pass to any `TTY#`(except with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
2. Only close the window that I'm trying to close;

What can I do? 
Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

This bug was reported years ago to the devs team, but it is supposed to be fixed with the latest versions of Ubuntu.

If you're not using russian keyboard, I'd say you could just remove the package `console-cyrillic` responsible for this, or run this [patch](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/66071336/cyr.patch).

Source [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-cyrillic/+bug/520546)

EDIT: As comments suggest, updating grub with `sudo update-grub` seems to solve this issue, somehow

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, Kernel 4.4.0-31-generic. It's a new problem, days ago everything was working perfectly.

Comment: Are you using compiz?

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm running gnome-shell.

Comment: And does alt+f2 opens TTY2, alt+f3 tty3 etc..?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: I think this is kbd_mode issue, like it was with the cyrillic kb, I can reproduce this if I type `kbd_mode -u` in a terminal... Can you try with `kbd_mode -a` and see if the behavior is the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42839/discussion-between-pielco11-and-fluffy).

Comment: Was this ever resolved in chat? I'm having the same exact issue in a new Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 install.

Comment: Well, yes but I can't remember how. Days ago I got the same problem, but unexpectedly solved running `sudo update-grub` and/or with a reboot. How this help.
PS: Times ago, running the above command didn't help

Comment: @Pielco11 This happened to me yesterday with a 2-day old installation of 17.04 with a manually-installed Gnome. I did add a Cyrillic layout (Bulgarian traditional phonetic), but it didn't happen straight away. I used the machine for a day, and then, randomly, it started throwing me into the TTYs. I did run a `sudo update-grub` and rebooted afterwards, which solved the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Do I have to reboot after `sudo update-grub`?